# Regexp как убрать двойные слеши из угла?

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения, replace

Ребята у меня есть текст где встречаются url-ы с двойными слэшами.

Как выглядит регулярка для удаления одного из двух слешов ?

```
<p><a href="http://site.com//XYZ">abcd</a></p> заменить на <p><a href="http://site.com/XYZ">abcd</a></p>

<p><a href="//XYZ">abcd</a></p> заменить на <p><a href="/XYZ">abcd</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = 'http://site.com//aaa';
echo preg_replace('/(?<!:)[\/]{2,}/','/',$str); // http://site.com/aaa
```

JS

```js
var str = 'http://site.com//aaa';
console.log(str.replace(/(^|[^:])[/]{2,}/, '$1/', str));
```

Comment: но это не javascript? )

Comment: @Nofate Сорри, попутал

Comment: Добавил вариант для JS

Comment: Ответ с ошибкой.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach(function(link) {
  var href = link.getAttribute('href').replace(/(^|[^:])\/\//, '$1/')
  console.log(href);
  link.setAttribute('href', href)
});
```

```html
<p><a href="http://site.com//XYZ">abcd</a></p> заменить на <p><a href="http://site.com/XYZ">abcd</a></p>

<p><a href="//XYZ">abcd</a></p> заменить на <p><a href="/XYZ">abcd</a></p>
```